# the name "photoveiwmodel" does not exist

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

i am using [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093) example and as soon as i opened it up i get the error

```
Error   1   The name "PhotosViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:PhotoHubSample.ViewModels".   C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\PhotoHub - Windows Phone 8 XAML LongListSelector Grid Layout sample\C#\PhotoHubSample\MainPage.xaml   73  12  PhotoHubSample
```

as this being a example i didn't expect their to be any errors when loading. i am still fairly new to making apps on windows phone, so i have no idea as to how to fix this..

Comment: try to rebuild the solution

Comment: my computer ended up crashing and restarting while i was away... it works not tho lol. visual studios is so strange sometime! ill have to remember to try rebuilding first if i have a problem. thanks!